# 7zip Extract to Specific Folder

Tags: batch-file, 7-zip

I've written a batch script with 7zip to extract an existing zip file to a specific folder. From what I've read in other forums it should be working....but it's not.

When I run just the basic extract script it extracts the file and saves it in the same location as the zip file.

```
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" x *.zip -y
```

But once I add the script to output to a specific folder it doesn't work.

```
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" x *.zip -o "C:\Users\<user-name>\Downloads\ShippingLabels" -y
```

Any help is appreciated. Also if anyone also knows how to get 7zip to open the extracted file after unzipping it that would be very helpful too!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Does the user extracting the files *have access* to the user's folders?

Try running the script as *Administrator* in an elevated CMD prompt, or by creating a shortcut to the batch file and setting the properties, using the *Shortcut* tab, *Advanced* button to `Run as administrator`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm writing this script for work, so I don't have administrator privileges on my computer. None the less the zip file in question is in the C:Downloads folder which is also where the new folder is located. Both locations are accessible to all users.